# Using linux find command to find directories and symbolic links to directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command, find

For a given directory tree in linux, I want to list:

- all directories ,
- all symbolic links to directories
- not directories found by following a symbolic link.

Consider an empty directory, and execute

```
mkdir a
mkdir a/b
ln -s a c
echo "x" > f1
ln -s f1 f2
```

Then `find . -type d` gives

```
.
./a
./a/b
```

and so misses the symbolic link `./c`, wheras `find . -type l` gives

```
./c
./f2
```

which misses the directories `.`, `./a`, and `./a/b`, and in addition prints the symbolic link `./f2` which is not a symbolic link to a directory, but to a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say:

```
while read -r name; do
  [ -d "$name" ] && echo "$name";
done < <(find .)
```

Comment: @HåkonHægland See the edit above.  It seems that `find` alone would be insufficient to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `-H` option:

> Cause the file information and file type (see stat(2)) returned for each symbolic link specified on the command line to be
>        those of the file referenced by the link, not the link itself.  If the referenced file does not exist, the file information and type will be for the link itself.  File information of all symbolic links not on the command line is that of the
>                link itself.

So:

```
find -H . -type d
```

will list directories and links to directories.

Comment: Hmm, looks like it's version-dependent. That documentation I quoted is from the BSD version in OS X. But GNU find in Linux is different.

Comment: GNU find has `-L`, but it also makes it recurse through links to directories.

Comment: It must be specified right after find to work: `find -L . -type d`.

Comment: I accidentally downvoted the post. Please take my apologies for that! Can somebody please revert my vote?

Comment: Thanks but the system says that my vote is locked until the post is edited :(

Answer (score 0):

```
find -L .... -type d ...
```

This will list both directories and links to directories as find will follow the symbolic link and qualify its target to see if it matches the required constraints.

-H will NOT follow symbolic links (the default).